# Entrust - This cache store does not support tagging in Laravel 5.1

Tags: database, caching, laravel-5, entrust

After searching all possible answers, I still dont know how to solve this problem. I'm using **zizaco/entrust** package for laravel, and everytime I save data into the **database** it returns an **error**:

> BadMethodCallException in Repository.php line 294: 
>   This cache store does not support tagging.

They said, I just have to use `CACHE_DRIVER=array` and others said `use memcached or redis`. Do I have to use `array`? Some say that it is the right way to solve the problem. Or can I use `cache` without **tagging** ?

**T.I.A.**

Answer (score 4):

In your `.env` file, change:

```
CACHE_DRIVER=file
```

**TO**

```
CACHE_DRIVER=array
```

After this change you might have to execute the following commands in the command line:

```
php artisan config:clear
php artisan config:cache
```

Answer (score 0):

Cache tags are not supported when using the `file` or `database` as cache driver.
So switching it to `array` will fix your error. You can use `memcache` or `apc` as well in case they're installed on your server. Read more about it at https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/cache#cache-tags